# Mysterious style attribute inserted into input type-password after page loaded

Tags: html, firefox, input, passwords, placeholder

Mysterious style attribute insert into input type-password tag after page loaded!?

```
Page source:
<input type="password" placeholder="password">
Style sheet:
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #999999;
}
After Load (Firebug):
<input type="password" placeholder="password" style="font-weight: 500; font-style: normal; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
```

Screenshot, [image: black placeholder instead of grey] 
Example, http://jsfiddle.net/LaxkL/ 
Effect, change the placeholder color, and it happens to type=password only 
Affected browser, Firefox 13+ (the first version I used on Mac) on Mac OS X 
**Question, how can I fix this, so all input placeholders have same color?**

Comment: Updated to clarify my question.

Comment: I would bet you have an extension that adds that style attribute.  Do you see this behavior in safe mode or just with all extensions disabled?

Answer (score 0):

I'm viewing this on Firefox 16.0.1 and there doesn't seem to be a problem. It's likely something that was fixed as support for the placeholder attribute grew.

Comment: I use FF 16.0.1 now, but it is still same. I just add a screenshot. You can see -moz-placeholder is not working.

Comment: I certainly see it in your screenshot, but I cannot duplicate. Maybe it would be helpful to describe the exact steps. "After Load (Firebug):" is a bit vague.